# How do I return blank cells using nullif for data type of date?

Tags: sql

I am currently returning '' for values that are equal to '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000':

```
select sec_sym,
isnull(cast(nullif(sec_expire,'1899-12-30 00:00:00.000') as varchar(39)),'') as [Spot Date],
isnull(cast(nullif(maturity,'1899-12-30 00:00:00.000') as varchar(39)),'') as [Maturity Date],
isnull(cast(nullif(sec_expire,'1899-12-30 00:00:00.000') as varchar(39)),'') as [Expiration Date] 
from tr_sec (nolock)
```

Of course, this will return date time values as string values (i.e. 'Feb 20 2016 12:00AM'). However, I would like to have these as data type 'date' (i.e. '2016-03-20').

```
select sec_sym,
    isnull(cast(nullif(sec_expire,'1899-12-30 00:00:00.000') as date),'') as [Spot Date],
    isnull(cast(nullif(maturity,'1899-12-30 00:00:00.000') as date),'') as [Maturity Date],
    isnull(cast(nullif(sec_expire,'1899-12-30 00:00:00.000') as date),'') as [Expiration Date] 
    from tr_sec (nolock)
```

Unfortunately, instead of returning blank cell values-like when using varchar-it inputs a placeholder.

Does this have to do with the database I am querying, or is there a way to remedy this datatype issue? Thank you for any suggestions on this one!

Comment: You should mention which database you are using.

Comment: If you want to use date datatypes, then return `NULL` for missing values.  If you want to format the dates into strings, then you can represent the missing values as strings.  Either dates or strings, not both.

Comment: The date you're using is the zero date for Access and Excel, and will appear to be a missing value in those applications, but it won't necessarily show up as missing in other environments--and it looks like you're not using Access, given your syntax.